# How to get WhatsApp campaigns click data

Tags: marketing-cloud

We are in the process of integrating WhatsApp with SFMC and have carried out several campaigns. However, we have noticed that while analyzing the WhatsApp reports, SFMC only provides data on Deliveries and Reads, but not on Clicks. Can you suggest a solution that will enable us to obtain WhatsApp Click data too? We use update contact activity but that won't help.

Answer (score 0):

To track links what you can do is use a url shortner, this will allow you to track information based on if the link has been opened.

Also, by using a shortner that has an api you could later import this info automatically to SF.

Try the free plan of something like [bit.ly](https://bit.ly) or search for trackable url shortner and you will have what you are searching for.

Comment: Hello @santiparris,
apart from bit.ly option is there any way how we get the click data

Comment: Hi @shivkumarDusad, If the target site is connected to google analytics you could implement UTM Parameters (e.g., ?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email). Then you can interpret these parameters and show you where clicks came from.

I think using a link shortner is a much simpler and easier solution.

Comment: Yes, you are right but we don't use a link shortener, and Google Analytics is not connected to SFMC, is there any way like update contact activity?

Comment: I cannot think of any way of checking if the link has been opened for already completed campaigns. My best recommendation is to try and implement branded/tracked links in new whatsapp campaigns.